# Como montar uma lista no Controller e montar um DropDownlist

Tags: c#, razor

tenho a seguinte dificuldade.

Minha classe endereços tem o `TipoEndereco`, queria montar um dropdownlist

Monto uma lista no controller?
Pego ela na view?

Obrigado.

Comment: O que você tem? Essa questão pode gerar muitos resultados. Seja mais específico para podermos ajudá-lo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346376/how-to-displaying-a-list-of-objects-in-mvc-view

Comment: `TipoEndereco` é um Enum?

Comment: não, string mesmo @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: Da uma olhada no link que mandei @Furlan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com String fica assim:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TipoEndereco, new List<String> { "Residencial", "Comercial" }.Select(option => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = option,
            Value = option,
            Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.TipoEndereco == option)
        }), "Selecione...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Ou você faz do jeito performático e cria um Enum:

```
public enum TipoEndereco
{
    Residencial,
    Comercial
}
```

E usa assim:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TipoEndereco, Enum.GetValues(typeof(TipoTelefone)).OfType<TipoEndereco>().Select(option => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = option.ToString(),
            Value = option.ToString(),
            Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.TipoEndereco == option)
        }), "Selecione...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```